# Write a query that returns all parents on top and then children

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-data

Table structure:

```
|--------------------------------|-------------|
|branchid   |branchcode |parentid|branchtypeid |
|-----------------------|--------|-------------|
|438        |UKHQR      |438     |  2          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|539        |UKBRS      |438     |  1          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|3683       |UKSNL      |438     |  2          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|3110       |UKNNX      |3683    |  1          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|987        |FNOLR      |987     |  2          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|1014       |FNHLK      |987     |  1          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|3371       |FNHPO      |987     |  2          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|990        |FNAAA      |3371    |  1          |
|--------------------------------|-------------|
```

### Levels

1. A `branchcode` whose `branchid` and `parentid` are the same and `branchtypeid` is 2 is the first parent branch.
2. A `branchcode` whose `branchid` and `parentid` are **not** the same but `branchtypeid` is 2 is the second parent branch, otherwise it is a child branch.
3. Child branches should be sorted in the way their parent branches are ordered.

### Required output

`|--------------------------------|-------------|
|branchid   |branchcode |parentid|branchtypeid |
|-----------------------|--------|-------------|
|438        |UKHQR      |438     |  2          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|987        |FNOLR      |987     |  2          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|3683       |UKSNL      |438     |  2          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|3371       |FNHPO      |987     |  2          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|539        |UKBRS      |438     |  1          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|3110       |UKNNX      |3683    |  1          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|1014       |FNHLK      |987     |  1          |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-------------|
|990        |FNAAA      |3371    |  1          |
|--------------------------------|-------------|`

What I've already done:

```
SELECT branchcode,branchid,parentid
   FROM branches
      START WITH parentid IN ( SELECT parentid FROM branches where parentid = branchid)
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR  parentid = branchid
     ORDER SIBLINGS BY parentid;
```

Comment: It would help to include the - in the question - output you are trying to achieve for that data; and also to say what the problem is with your current query.

Comment: It also isn't clear how many levels of data you want, and how they should be ordered/displayed. For example, UKSNL is a child of UKHQR, but is also a parent of UKNNX; so should UKNNX not be shown at all? And if it should be then where is it shown?

Comment: Change two things: `start with branchid in ...` (not `parentid`) and `connect by prior branchid = parentid`. This [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=141066b9ee496b3e21f8f2b00a2184eb) returns additional columns lvl, path, root, you can use them for ordering if you need the other order. Root rows have lvl=1.

Comment: @Alex Poole, you are right and i have updated the question. See it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code - assuming you want all levels of data returned - is that you are only getting the rows with a top-level parent - i.e. levels 1 and 2. That's because your `start with` clause is looking for any parent ID; and then your `connect by` is searching the wrong way. So you query gets six rows:

```
BRANCHCODE   BRANCHID   PARENTID
---------- ---------- ----------
UKHQR             438        438
UKBRS             539        438
UKSNL            3683        438
FNOLR             987        987
FNHLK            1014        987
FNHPO            3371        987
```

.. all with one of the two original top-level IDs, 438 or 987.

If you fix those, firstly to get the two true top-level parents (instead of using a subquery) and then reversing the connect-by:

```
SELECT branchcode, branchid, parentid
FROM branches
START WITH parentid = branchid
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE parentid = PRIOR branchid
ORDER SIBLINGS BY parentid;

BRANCHCODE   BRANCHID   PARENTID
---------- ---------- ----------
UKHQR             438        438
UKBRS             539        438
UKSNL            3683        438
UKNNX            3110       3683
FNOLR             987        987
FNHLK            1014        987
FNHPO            3371        987
FNAAA             990       3371
```

... you get all 8 rows, in a more normal order. Incidentally, the `nocycle` is only needed because of the way your top-level is defined; it's more common in my experience for the root elements parent ID to be null. Anyway, another way to avoid that loop is to do:

```
CONNECT BY parentid = PRIOR branchid AND branchid != PRIOR parentid
```

But I digress. You can add more information including an indented view of the hierarchy:

```
SELECT branchcode, branchid, parentid,
  lpad(' ', level - 1, ' ') || branchcode as nestedbranch
FROM branches
START WITH parentid = branchid
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE parentid = PRIOR branchid
ORDER SIBLINGS BY parentid;

BRANCHCODE   BRANCHID   PARENTID NESTEDBRANCH   
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
UKHQR             438        438 UKHQR          
UKBRS             539        438  UKBRS         
UKSNL            3683        438  UKSNL         
UKNNX            3110       3683   UKNNX        
FNOLR             987        987 FNOLR          
FNHLK            1014        987  FNHLK         
FNHPO            3371        987  FNHPO         
FNAAA             990       3371   FNAAA
```

But you said you wanted all parents at the top, which is a bit odd, and leaves rows that are both a parent and a child in a bit of an indeterminate state. You could potentially do this by using a case expression in the ordering, perhaps including the root element for context (and the level if that's useful), e.g.:

```
SELECT branchcode, branchid, parentid,
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT(branchcode) AS rootbranch,
  lpad(' ', level - 1, ' ') || branchcode as nestedbranch
FROM branches
START WITH parentid = branchid
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE parentid = PRIOR branchid
ORDER BY CASE WHEN branchid = parentid THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, -- puts all parents first
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT(branchid), level, branchcode;

BRANCHCODE   BRANCHID   PARENTID ROOTBRANCH NESTEDBRANCH   
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
UKHQR             438        438 UKHQR      UKHQR          
FNOLR             987        987 FNOLR      FNOLR          
UKBRS             539        438 UKHQR       UKBRS         
UKSNL            3683        438 UKHQR       UKSNL         
UKNNX            3110       3683 UKHQR        UKNNX        
FNHLK            1014        987 FNOLR       FNHLK         
FNHPO            3371        987 FNOLR       FNHPO         
FNAAA             990       3371 FNOLR        FNAAA
```

but that still doesn't seem very useful... so perhaps you really meant to have each parent before its children, which the earlier query does.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64574fde41a228c8c1541a4970e91059)

Comment: thanks. You are almost there though the question has been updated.